# 'int' object is not subscriptable while using reduce

Tags: python, list, lambda, reduce, self

I have an issue that I cannot add the values with reduce

```
sum_of_cols = lambda self,col : reduce(lambda d,d1: d[col] + d1[col] ,self.my_list)
```

- self.my_list-list of dicts d[col]
- List item-contains int object

Comment: Use a `def` statement in place of the outer lambda expression.

Answer (score 0):

`d` is the running sum, not something with columns.

```
def sum_of_cols(self, col):
    return reduce(lambda d, d1: d + d1[col], self.my_list, 0)
```

Comment: i cannot, the exercise says that i cannot use def

Comment: Then stick with the lambda expression. The relevant change is not trying to index `d`.

Comment: awww
now its "  :unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'int'  "

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```
sum_of_cols = lambda self,col :reduce(lambda d,d1: d + d1 ,list(map(lambda k : k[col], self.my_list)))
```